# Is it possible to update element on a different page with jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page where user submits data.

```
/user1.php

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '/myDB.php',
    data: {
         'val' : val
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (response) {
         // update user1.php
    }
});
```

I use jQuery `$.ajax()` to POST this data to a second page where I store the data into db and return response back to **user.php** if successful.

```
/myDB.php

$userData = $_POST['userData'];    

// STORE DATA IN DB

echo '{ "status": "Ok" }';

// update user2.php > $('#em').text($userData);
```

Is it possible to use jQuery to update another element on a page viewed by second user?

```
/user2.php 

<div id="em"></div>
```

I know I can `.load()` part of content from another page, just wondering if there was a reverse flow possibility.

Thanks

Comment: Normally the second page would poll periodically to see if anything has changed. But you could also use `WebSockets` to keep a permanent connection open and have the server send changes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is check if anything change:

**checkupdate.php**

```
<?php

// Check database

$res = Array('changed' => false)

if ($data = $res->fetch();){
    $res['changed'] = true;
    $res['data'] = $data;
}

exit(json_encode($res));
```

On your second page:

```
function checkupdate(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/checkupdate.php',
        data: {
             'val' : val
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.changed){
               // do whatever with reponse.data
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
           // Do whatever when error
           console.log(e);
        },
        complete: function(){
        // Always when finish request do again
        setTimeout(checkupdate, 5);

        }
    });
}
```

Like Barmar says, you can do with Sockets, but isn't the best way.

Comment: Thanks, I am leaning towards periodic polling instead of websocket solution. Couple of questions: I pass val from another page, why do I need it here? And, why do I need to run this function if it completes running?

Comment: @santa, you don't need pass the `val`, is just a example... I thought you wanted check constantly the changes, if you wanna just the first change you can put the `setTimeout` on `else` of `if(response.changed)`...